Generate a report on GA4 using Data Layer Variables
I want to be able to generate a report based on a Data Layer Variable that is sent to Google Analytics 4.
For simplicitys sake, assume i send in a BookID to GA:
dataLayer.push({
    'book_id': <%= BookID %>
});

In Google Tag Manager Variables, I've also set up an Event Settings as well as a Data Layer Variable

In the Data Layer Variable configuration, it is referenced to the ID Event Settings

And in the Event Settings, it is referenced in the MY_APP Tag.

And when i preview this using the debugger, it shows up no problem:

What im trying to achieve: Before Google did their update, I was using the API to basically bring me stats for how many people have visited the page for a specific Book. Now after the update, I just want to be able to generate a simple report and be able to use Book_ID as a metric. For example, to see which book has the most page views.

What was missing was a GA4 event tag
